# Join 3 tables complex condition

Tags: sql

I have a requirement to join three tables which have the same structure as shown below.

[image: Results obtained from sql]

I need to join these tables based on the store and date field values as shown below:

[image: Desired Result]

The complex part here is that even if the row in a table does not match with the other tables, it should create a new row with the other values as zero. For example if there is no shipped and allocated quantities for a store on a particular day but if there is a canceled quantity on that day, a new row should be created with shipped $ allocated values set to 0 and cancelled field value set to the correct value. Can anybody suggest the best method to approach this?

Comment: Please provide sample data -- for all three tables -- and desired results.  An appropriate database tag would help.

Comment: [how-to-ask](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). please do not post sample data as images.

Comment: Where do allocated_qty and cancel_qty come from?

Comment: Similiar to the table image posted above , there are two more tables for allocated and canceled.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
    select alldates.procdate,
           alldates.store,
           st.quantity as ship_quantity,
           ct.quantity as cancel_quantity,
           at.quantity as allocation_quantity
     from (select procdate, store from shp_table union
           select procdate, store from cnl_table union
           select procdate, store from aloc_table) alldates
left join shp_table st on alldates.procdate = st.procdate and alldates.store = st.store
left join cnl_table ct on alldates.procdate = ct.procdate and alldates.store = ct.store
left join aloc_table at on alldates.procdate = at.procdate and alldates.store = at.store
```